# How does ImageView just redraw part of its content when invalidate(Rect) is called?

Tags: android, view, invalidation

I am new to Android development, just reading docs and trying the
APIs. I am quit confused how ImageView managed to draw just a part of
its content after an invalidate(Rect) invocation.

I've checked ImageView.java, found no other drawing method except
onDraw(Canvas), but onDraw(Canvas) only cut the drawable only if it is
beyound the view's visible boundary.
I also read the implementation of View.invalidate(Rect), I think the
key of this function is calling to
    mParent.invalidateChild(this, r);
However, I think the parent view doesn't know how to draw the child in
the given Rect, it finally has to call some method of it child to
paint out.

Has anybody investigated this part of codes? Would you please give me
some guide?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can gather there are two optimizations going one. For one, if the child is a viewgroup, only those children of this group are redrawn that intersect the invalidated area. Also, the canvas is clipped to the bounds of this rect. This means that less pixels have to be shuffled through the bus to the framebuffer, and that draw operations that are clipped completely can be skipped.

This is a semi-educated guess. I browsed the source a few months back and am fairly certain of the ViewGroup thing. The second one can be tested by overriding clipping in onDraw and checking if it redraws everything.

Comment: I am a novice to android and I have a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027199/am-i-invalidating-the-entire-screen-on-every-call

Please provide the answer if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that code is in the `View` class.

There are some two interesting answers from Romain Guy in the google group.

- [Incorrect clip rect in onDraw()?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/844e7a9c5f007cc8/9d407ae8f2b0076a?lnk=gst&q=invalidate+Rect#9d407ae8f2b0076a)
- [How android.view.View.invalidate(i nt l, int t, int r, int b) make only the dirty area redrawn?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a5eb2d13a979530d/b77768f770f4b53e?lnk=gst&q=invalidate+Rect#b77768f770f4b53e)

Comment: -1 as both links are now dead. Including some of their content here would have been better.

Comment: +1 because the links are not dead... I just tested them.  However, I agree that adding content is a good thing to do in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think android draw the view just like canvas in j2me, all the draw code is not draw directly to hardware ( screen ), it just draw to a buffer or drawable or something. When we call View.invalidate(Rect), teh system copy the image in the rect of the buffer( or drawable) to hardware(screen).